# NullReferenceException when closing a threaded form

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

**Context :**

I created an Windows Form application which runs a splash screen before starting. Quickly, here is what contains my `Program.cs` :

```
public static Thread splashScreenThread = null;
public static FormSplashScreen formSplashScreen;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) {

    // Show splash screen
    splashScreenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowSplashScreen));
    splashScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
    splashScreenThread.Start();

    // Load some components in background
    LoadComponentsInBackground()

    // Hide the splash screen
    if (splashScreenThread != null) {
        formSplashScreen.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            formSplashScreen.Close();
            formSplashScreen.Dispose();
        }));
        splashScreenThread = null;
    }

    // Start now the application
    Application.Run();
}

private static void ShowSplashScreen() {
    formSplashScreen = new FormSplashScreen();
    formSplashScreen.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Problem :**

My problem does not happen everytime I start the application, it seems to be random and to occur more often on some PCs and less on others... So I'm a bit confused, besides I don't really understand where it comes from:

A `NullReferenceException` is raised on the `formSplashScreen.Invoke(...Close...)` line, but `formSplashScreen` is correctly initialized (I checked it while debugging).
I'm not sure if this comes from the thread or from another point...

**Possible solution :**

I could maybe surround the line causing problem with something like below, but it would only be getting round the problem and I'd rather like understanding it and properly solving it.

```
while (splashScreenThread != null) {
    try {
        formSplashScreen.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
            formSplashScreen.Close();
            formSplashScreen.Dispose();
        }));
        splashScreenThread = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like race condition.. try moving this code to be within `ShowSplashScreen` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a race condition that happens because the thread has been created and staterted but the SplashScreen has not been created yet.

In other words you're trying to close the splash screen before it was even created.

You can use [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) to make sure that the SplashScreen has been created or at least wait until it's not null.

Another option is to signal the screen it should close and let him handle the closing logic.

Comment: What do you mean with _"Wait event"_?

Comment: EventWaitHandle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx